# Parse JSON cross-domain - Use Tumblr API from javascript

Tags: javascript, json, tumblr

Is it possible to access the Tumblr API from javascript in a normal HTML page? The same origin policy seems to be in the way. Assuming I just want to access some url like [this](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&notes_info=true) (the key is the one from the api docs), is it possible to download and parse that json string with `JSON.parse` or something like that? I can't find anything helpful on google or here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jsonp support](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#responses) provided by Tumblr to overcome same origin policy

```
$.getJSON('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=<api-key>&notes_info=true&callback=?', function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

Or

```
$.getJSON('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/posts/photo?callback=?',{
    api_key: '<api-key>',
    notes_info: true
}, function(data){
    console.log('result', data)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rvm8X/)